# Reference request on dynamic flows combined with network coding

Tags: coding-theory, encoding, flow-problems

I have read some papers about network coding and dynamic flows (flows over time).

I think I have made comprehensive searches on google, google scholar and IEEE Xplore.
IMHO, the reasons for the difficulty in finding such references are that this topic is new and that there are not many people doing research on this topic.

As Kaveh's comment below, I am going to explain the problem with more detail.
The original network coding theory addresses the maximum flow problem under the circumstances that every node in the network can combine the information it receives, which is the counterpart of the maximum flow problem in the network with coding ability.

The quickest flow (flows over time) addresses the problem how soon a/some commodity/commodities can be transship to some certain nodes, and this model is applicable in, for example, evacuation. Some reference for the flows over time are [Quickest flows over time](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjls8L2jqTMAhXJj5QKHXd3Cj4QFggaMAA&url=%68%74%74%70%3A%2F%2F%70%61%67%65%2E%6D%61%74%68%2E%74%75%2D%62%65%72%6C%69%6E%2E%64%65%2F%7E%73%6B%75%74%65%6C%6C%61%2F%46%6C%65%69%73%63%68%65%72%53%6B%75%74%65%6C%6C%61%2E%70%64%66&usg=AFQjCNFgTRCo08WLCZzlqKLpQ7-sfB-MwQ) and [Multicommodity flows over time](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjls8L2jqTMAhXJj5QKHXd3Cj4QFghFMAQ&url=%68%74%74%70%3A%2F%2F%77%77%77%2E%73%63%69%65%6E%63%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%2E%63%6F%6D%2F%73%63%69%65%6E%63%65%2F%61%72%74%69%63%6C%65%2F%70%69%69%2F%53%30%33%30%34%33%39%37%35%30%37%30%30%31%35%30%38&usg=AFQjCNFU-JIbTin6uMHsZN2kjfT5cm_SIw).

The problem I am interested in is how to combine the coding ability, as in the network coding theory, to the quickest flow model. Once the network has coding ability, there maybe some promotion in the counterpart of the quickest flow.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know what network coding is. What is a "dynamic flow" and why are the two related?

Comment: Maximum flow problem addresses the route of the maximum bandwidth in a network, yet dynamic flows (flows over time) address the route of the quickest arrival. Because the transition of a commodity is not instantaneous in the model of dynamic flows, which is the reason why it is called "dynamic", the value of maximum flow is a function over time $t$ when considering dynamic flows. http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~lkf/papers/FS2.pdf might be a good reference for dynamic flows. The motivation to combine dynamic flow with network coding is to optimize the delay not only the bandwidth. @kodlu

Comment: I think you should edit your question and explain the problem you are interested in with a bit more detail. People like questions when they learn something new from reading it which means more people would read and think about your question and increase the chance of getting an answer.

Comment: You may find some relevant literature if you search for the terms "network coding" and "delay".